# struct timespec used in multiple source files: C

Tags: c, struct, header, extern, timespec

new user so I'm sorry if this explanation isn't clear enough...I am having trouble creating timespec variables to be modified/used between multiple source files. My program is meant to determine the time it takes to execute another program from within my initial program and therefore I'll need to clock the time in two source files and store it to be used later to determine the difference in time. I have been scouring the internet and tried different things but it always seems like my source files create different instances of the variables

Here's what my code basically looks like:

Header file:

```
//shared.h
#ifndef shared_h
#define shared_h
#include<time.h>

extern struct timespec callTime, startTime;

#endif
```

Source File1:

```
//shared.c
#include "shared.h"

struct timespec startTime = {0}, callTime = {0};
```

Source File2:

```
//app.c
#include "shared.h"
#include <time.h>

void main(){
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startTime);
}//end of main
```

Source File:

```
//timer.c
#include "shared.h"
#include <time.h>

void main(){

pid_t pid = fork();

clock_gettime(CLOCK MONOTONIC, &callTime);
if(pid == 0){
    execvp("./app", NULL);
    return 0;
}//end of if

printf("Call: %ld & Start: %ld\n", callTime.tv_sec, startTime.tv_sec);

return 0;
}//end of main
```

I will get something like...

> Call: 14928304940 & Start: 0

Hopefully this code gets the point across of what I'm trying to do. When it forks and executes the other program, the value for startTime will change but won't hold so that when I call it later in the Parent process. The value will just be it's initial value instead of the clocked time.  it seems Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciate!

Added Note: I do link shared.c with timer.c and app.c seperately and then run timer.c

```
gcc shared.h
gcc -c shared.c
gcc -c app.c
gcc -c timer.c
gcc -o app app.o shared.o
gcc timer.o shared.o
./a.out
```

Comment: You should have define the `struct` in `shared.h` and put `extern` keyword elsewhere in your code

Comment: External variables are shared between functions that are linked together. They're not shared between programs run by `exec`.

Comment: @Noob - No.  globals shared across compilation units (i.e. ".c" files) should be **declared** `extern` in the header and **defined** in one and only one C file.  Alternatively, you can just use `extern` in the other files.

Comment: you should use `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`.

Comment: variables can be shared across .c files in the SAME executable.  To have the first executable see both the start and end values, there needs to be some kind of communication back to the first executable that contains the end value.   perhaps using posix or system V messaging or some common shared memory

Comment: the exec... series of functions never 'return' unless there was some kind of error such that the requested new process failed to run.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  The compiler would then raise several warning statements, for instance about the incorrect declarations of main()  Those warnings need to be fixed before trying to run the code.

Comment: @user3629249: `-pedantic` is only useful if you're striving for absolute standards compliance.  There are many cases where GCC extensions are useful (or they wouldn't exist) and therefore `-pedantic` complains about otherwise perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is a misunderstanding of what `fork` does.  It gives the child process a *copy* of the parent processes memory.  Not the *same* memory....   well actually on sane architectures it IS the same memory w/o copy-on-write semantics, but don't worry about that for now.

Your child process (assuming `app.c` compiles to `app` here) will modify its own copy of startTime then exit w/o modifying the parent processes startTime variable.

If you want to have the child process communicate something back to the parent, you need to use some form of interprocess communication.

Comment: Thanks for explaining through my misconception Brian! I went ahead and simplified what I was doing by just writing to a separate file like you suggested b/c that actually does work best for what I am trying to accomplish(exporting the time data to excel)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do won't work.  Sharing variables like that only works when multiple source files are linked into the same executable, and even then only for a given running process.

You'll need to have the child process send a message back to the parent when it starts, preferably via a pipe, at which time the parent knows when the child started and can call `clock_gettime` a second time.

Comment: I think there are *much* simpler options here than calling `pipe`, `dup2` etc.  Why not just have `app` write the struct to a file?  Or use a shared memory?

Comment: Actually, that's probably the simplest thing to do.  If you put the child side of the pipe on file descriptor 1, the child just needs to call `printf` to write the data.  And that way, you don't need to worry about an external file.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was overlooking the fact that the parent needs a way to get notification that the child actually wrote something.    With that in mind, having the child send a signal, i.e. `kill( getppid(), SIG_SOMETHING)` might be easiest.  Or for that matter, in this trivial case, just call `wait` from the parent.

Comment: I guess it's hard to say what's "best" given that this is a a toy example.